# Setting position of UIView using IF statement

Tags: ios, uiview, ipad, cgpoint

In the application I am creating, I have a UIView named AdvancedView1.  The user can drag the view around the screen.  The user needs to drag the view to a certain position on the screen.  If the view is dropped into a certain area, then the view would "snap" into a defined location. When trying to use IF AND statements, I am getting an error.  Any suggestions?

Also  "origin" is a CGPoint declared in the .h file.

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
 {
     CGPoint origin = [gesture locationInView:[self superview]];
     [self bringSubviewToFront:[self superview]];
     [self setCenter:origin];            
}   
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
{
    if (origin.x >= 574.0 && origin.x <= 724.0 ) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(574.0, 184.0, self.frame.size.width,   self.frame.size.height);
    }
}   
}
```

I am getting the following error for "origin.x >= ...."

"Request for member "x" in something not a structure or union"

Answer (score 1):

`origin` variable scope is limited to the 1st if block and it is not visible in the 2nd one. Move its declaration to the function scope:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
   CGPoint origin = [gesture locationInView:[self superview]];
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
   {     
        [self bringSubviewToFront:[self superview]];
        [self setCenter:origin];            
   }   
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
   {
       if (origin.x >= 574.0 && origin.x <= 724.0 ) {
          self.frame = CGRectMake(574.0, 184.0, self.frame.size.width,   self.frame.size.height);
       }
   }   
}
```